# C# get all possible combinations

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, foreach, combinations

I have a List of Custom Class inside a class

```
public class CustomImage
{ 
    public CustomImage(Image image,string Hash)
    {
        this.Image = image;
        this.HashCode = Hash;
    }
    public Image Image { get; set; }

    public string HashCode { get; set; }
}

 public class Layer
{
    public List<CustomImage> Images { get; set; }
    
    public Layer(string folderPath)
    {
        //....
    }
    public string HashCode { get; set; }
    //....
}
```

And inside my Form I have:  `public List<Layer> Layers = new List<Layer>();`

```
  private Image[] Test()
    {
        Image First = Layers[0].Images[0].Image;

        Image Second = Layers[1].Images[0].Image;

        Image Third = Layers[2].Images[0].Image;

        return new Image[] { First, Second, Third };
    }
```

and after : `Image Third = Layers[2].Images[1].Image;`

and after :`Image Third = Layers[2].Images[2].Image;`

When the Third Image Loop is all done then it will start doing the second one.

`Image Second = Layers[1].Images[1].Image; Image Third = Layers[2].Images[0].Image;`

`Image Second = Layers[1].Images[1].Image; Image Third = Layers[2].Images[1].Image;`

It should get 1 image from each layer in Layers List and return an Image List. I couldn't find any solutions for getting all combinations. Can you help me?

[What I am aiming for as an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eS9k6.png)

Comment: What do want? Can you give an example input with the expected output? Each layer can have several images, but you only want one image. Which one do you want? What do you mean by combinations?

Comment: @Hebele Hübele do you want to  get the list of images in array from the list of Layer inside the Form object?

Comment: I edited the question maybe you can understand it better.

Comment: You just need two for loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we can put these combinations into a sorted order, then it we can use a loop to get each combination. If every layer had ten images, then this would be quite easy. For example, with 4 layers, we would get 4-digit numbers. 5327 would mean 5th image of 1st layer, 3rd images of 2nd layer, 2nd image of 3rd layer, 7th image of fourth layer. If every layer has the not ten, but the same amount of images, this also quite easy. We just have to go to a different digit system. For example, if every layer had 16 images, you could you hexadecimal numbers.

But your case is more complicated, because every layer can have an individual number of images. Hence we have to use a custom digit system, where every digit uses a custom power. For example, if there are two layer with first layer having 3 images, and second layer having  5 images, there are 15 combinations. We can write every number from 0 to 14 as `a*5 + b` with `a < 3` and `b < 5`.

You can use this method to achieve what you want:

```
public static IEnumerable<CustomImage[]> GetCombinations(List<Layer> input)
{
    int[] factors = new int[input.Count + 1];
    factors[factors.Length - 1] = 1;
    for(int i = factors.Length - 2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        factors[i] = factors[i+1] * input[i].Images.Count;
    }
    int max = factors[0];
        
    for(int j = 0; j < max; j++)
    {
        CustomImage[] result = new CustomImage[input.Count];
        for(int i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
        {
            result[i] = input[i].Images[j / factors[i+1] % input[i].Images.Count];
        }
        yield return result;
    }
}
```

In the first step, we fill an array called factors. The last element of the array will be 1. The array is then filled from behind. Each element is the product of the following element and the amount of images of the layer with the same index. For example, if we have three layers with 2, 2 and 3 images, the element will be from behind:

- 1 (fixed for the last element)
- 3*1 = 3 (last layer has three images)
- 2*3 = 6 (layer before last layer has two images)
- 2*6 = 12 (layer before that layer has again two images)

The first element of this array is the product of all amounts of images of all layers and thus the amount of combinations.

The we setup a loop which will produce all combinations. We take one image from each layer. The index inside each layer can be calculated by dividing through the next factor and then doing a modulo division through the amount of images of the layer.

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jhk18u

Answer (score 0):

@Hebele Hübele, as suggested by @Liam . you need two for loops:

```
        var imageArray = new Image[1];
        //loop the layers
        foreach (var layer in layers) {
            //and for each layer loop images
            foreach (var imgObject in layer.Images) {
                imageArray.Append(imgObject.Image)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Okay but I don't want this. I put an image so you can understand it better . And sorry I am not good at English